# executequery in Grails doesn't load key : value json

Tags: mysql, json, grails, grails-orm

I m doing something like this to get the data...

```
 def prods = Product.executeQuery("select category.id,category.name, avg(competition1Price), avg(competition2Price), avg(onlineCompetitionPrice) from Product group by category.id")
        render prods as JSON
```

Not the output I'm getting is this..

```
        [[1,"Colchones y",1657.4784,2071.5,1242.5]]
```

these are just the values..

I want to use the same query and get key value pair..
like the way you do using findAll(query)
But I can't seem to implement this query using findAll()

Please Help

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

That's because the instances of prods are just objects with the result of your query and not instances of Product or other domain class (you used HQL that not represents a domain class). You can:

- consider using a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) for this query and mapping as a domain class;
- manually build the output;

The second option is something like (not tested):

```
  def output = [[:]]
  prods.each { result ->
    def prod = ['category.id' : result[0] , 'category.name': result[1]] //and so on...
    output << prod
  }
  render output as JSON
```

Using this second option, to change the result produced, just cange the structure of your map. You can also have a list of maps if needed.

Comment: and how to use a vie for this query and mapping as a domain class??

Comment: Do you know how to create a database view? The mapping is pretty the same of a table.

Comment: No ..can you please provide some links .. and the 2nd option worked fine. but it's still not in the format I need it. I need it something like.. { rows: [ { "id": "22",
   "CategoryName": "spurTree13",
            "CategoryRole": "Profit Driver1",
            "PrimaryObjective": "Increase Volume1",},{so on...}]}